# Unresolved org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1 Intellij - Maven Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, maven-3, sonarlint

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2016.1 working in an imported Maven project.
Intellij complains only about sonar-maven-plugin.

I have already tried to reimport in maven option but Intellij stills mad with this plugin.

The error message in Intellij is: 
Unresolved plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1

[image]

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T09:41:47-07:00)   
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.9   
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation   
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8     
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the artifact with Maven coordinates `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1` is a [`pom`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.1) file in Maven Central and not a `jar`, so it cannot be resolved properly.

The latest official version of the plugin using these coordinates is [`2.7.1`](http://www.mojohaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)

The `sonar-maven-plugin` has changed then coordinates, moving to a new `groupId`: [`org.sonarsource.scanner.maven`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin), which indeed provides the [`3.0.1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.1) version.

You should hence change the existing coordinates used by your `pom.xml` file to:

```
<groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
```

That's also documented on the official [Sonarqube Maven documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).

Comment: @fsantos did this answer help you out?

Comment: Absolutelly @A_Di-Matteo. Thanks a lot!